# How can a React application (Chrome extension) communicate with the Chrome devtools API?

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

I have a small Chrome extension that I want able to display request entries in a devtool tab.

The repository is here: https://github.com/angrybacon/dydu-skadi/blob/a6c25106f591398217cc804ff1d025a8d6279814/public/devtools.js .

How can I have access to the 2 values (labelled `Request` and `Response`) from the React application?

Adding actual code, as per request.

`public/devtools.js`

```
chrome.devtools.panels.create('Dydu Skadi', null, 'index.html', null);
chrome.devtools.network.onRequestFinished.addListener(requestHandler);


function requestHandler(entry) {
  const url = document.createElement('a');
  url.href = entry.request.url;
  if (!url.pathname.includes('chatHttp')) {
    return;
  }
  entry.getContent(content => {
    const parameters = {};
    for (const pair of new URLSearchParams(url.search.substr(1)).entries()) {
      parameters[pair[0]] = JSON.parse(pair[1]);
    };
    console.log('Request', parameters);
    console.log('Response', JSON.parse(content.replace(/.*\((.*)\)/, '$1')));
  });
}
```

`src/components/Application/index.js`

```
import React from 'react';


class Application extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return null;
  }
}


export default Application;
```

How do I display these values:

```
console.log('Request', parameters);
console.log('Response', JSON.parse(content.replace(/.*\((.*)\)/, '$1')));
```

From my React component `Application`?

Comment: Can you add any details like: code used, error problem encountered? [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) Show the community what you have tried.

Comment: @Mr.Rebot The code used is under the frozen link to my repository, in `devtools.js`. I can log what I need using `chrome.devtools` API from that file but can't figure out where to start as to how to utilize the API results from my React application. Hope that clarifies a bit.